# Using a schedule in SQL without making the table huge

Tags: mysql, sql

So I've designed a basic SQL database that imports data outputted by machines through SSIS into SQL, does a few transforms, and ends up with how many things we are producing every 15 minutes.

Now we want to be able to report on this per-operator.  So I have another table with operators and operator numbers, and am trying to figure out how to track this, with the eventual goal of giving my boss charts and graphs of how his employees are doing.

Now the question:
I was going to format a table with the date, machine number, operator number and then a column for each 15m segment in a day, but that ended up being a million+ datapoints a year, which will clearly get out of control.

Then I was thinking, date, machinenumber, user#, start and stop time.  but couldn't figure out how to get it to roll over into the next day if a shift goes past midnight, or how to query against a time between the start/stop times, simple stuff I'm sure but I'm new here.  I need to use time instead of just a "shift" since that may change, people go home early, ect. stuff happens.

So the question is: What would be best practice on how to format a table for a work schedule, and how can I query off of it as above?

Comment: You're going to need to take a shot at this and show us what you've got. Right now this question is way too open-ended, there's a billion ways to do it, all of which might be valid for your use case. You can narrow that down by showing us a schema and a query.

Comment: A million datapoints a year isn't a lot of data. Even a sub $100 hard drive can store billions.

Comment: A [properly normalized database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) can easily handle your volume.

Answer (score 1):

First, a million rows a year isn't a lot. SQL databases regularly get into the billions of rows. The storage requirements compared to modern drive sizes are nothing. Properly indexed, performance won't be a problem.

In fact, I'd say to consider not even bothering with the time periods. Record each data point with a timestamp instead. Use SQL operators such as `BETWEEN` to get whatever periods you like. It's simpler. It's more flexible. It takes more space, but space isn't really an issue. And with proper indexing it won't be a performance issue. Use the money saved on developer time to buy better hardware for your database, like more RAM or an SSD. Or move to a cloud database.

Just make sure you architect your system to encapsulate the details of the schema, probably by using a [model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), and ensure that you have a way to safely change your schema, like by using [migrations](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html). Then if you need to re-architect your schema later you can do so without having to hunt down every piece of code that might use that table.

That said, there's a few simple things you could do to reduce the number of rows.

There's probably going to be a lot of periods when a thing doesn't produce anything. If nothing is produced during that period, don't store a row. If you just store the timestamp for each thing produced, these gaps appear normally.

You could save a small amount of space and performance by putting the periods in their own table and referencing them. So instead of every table having redundant `start` and `end` datetime columns, they'd have a single `period` column which referenced a `period` table that had `start` and `end` columns. While this would reduce some duplication, I'm not so sure this is worth the complexity.

---

In the end, before you add a bunch of complexity over hypothetical performance issues, do the simplest thing and benchmark it. Load up your database with a bunch of test data, see how it performs, and optimize from there.

Comment: Followup:
Between would work in one way, but what if I was going the other day

Example:
I have a time of 1:15, I'm trying to run a command to come back with a row which has a timestart of 1:00 and a timestart of 2:00 (for example)

Instead of selecting a row contained between two values, I'm trying to  start with the value, and select the row that the value falls between (if that makes sense)

Is that doable or should I go back and rethink the problem?

Comment: @Metal Sorry, that doesn't make sense.